Making Grammatically Correct Currency Number to Text With Commas & Hyphens
I have a VBA code to convert currency numbers to text. BUT, it is not grammatically correct.
Example: I type 113,729 and it converts to One Hundred Thirteen Thousand Seven Hundred Twenty Nine Dollars.
What I WANT it to look like is: One Hundred Thirteen Thousand, Seven Hundred Twenty-Nine Dollars. And same if it goes to million. 1,113,729 - One Million, Thirteen Thousand, Seven Hundred Twenty-Nine Dollars.
Is that possible?
  'Main Function
  Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
      Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
      Dim DecimalPlace, Count
      ReDim Place(9) As String
      Place(2) = " Thousand "
      Place(3) = " Million "
      Place(4) = " Billion "
      Place(5) = " Trillion "

      MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))
      DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
      If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
          Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
                    "00", 2))
          MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
      End If
      Count = 1
      Do While MyNumber <> ""
          Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
          If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
          If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
              MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
          Else
              MyNumber = ""
          End If
          Count = Count + 1
      Loop
      Select Case Dollars
          Case ""
              Dollars = "No Dollars"
          Case "One"
              Dollars = "One Dollar"
           Case Else
              Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"
      End Select
      Select Case Cents
          Case ""
              Cents = " and No Cents"
          Case "One"
              Cents = " and One Cent"
                Case Else
              Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
      End Select
      SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
  End Function

  Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
      Dim Result As String
      If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
      MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
      ' Convert the hundreds place.
      If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
          Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
      End If
      ' Convert the tens and ones place.
      If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
          Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
      Else
          Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
      End If
      GetHundreds = Result
  End Function

  Function GetTens(TensText)
      Dim Result As String
      Result = "" ' Null out the temporary function value.
      If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then   ' If value between 10-19&hellip;
          Select Case Val(TensText)
              Case 10: Result = "Ten"
              Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
              Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
              Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
              Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
              Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
              Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
              Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
              Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
              Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
              Case Else
          End Select
      Else ' If value between 20-99&hellip;
          Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
              Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
              Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
              Case 4: Result = "Forty "
              Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
              Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
              Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
              Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
              Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
              Case Else
          End Select
          Result = Result & GetDigit _
              (Right(TensText, 1))  ' Retrieve ones place.
      End If
      GetTens = Result
  End Function

  Function GetDigit(Digit)
      Select Case Val(Digit)
          Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
          Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
          Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
          Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
          Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
          Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
          Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
          Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
          Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
          Case Else: GetDigit = ""
      End Select
  End Function```


During your loop, why not check if you are at the third character and add in a comma?

1,113,729 - One Million, Thirteen Thousand, Seven Hundred Twenty-Nine Dollars ... that is not correct

Since the commas go with your defined breakpoints, change your definitions:
Place(2) = " Thousand, "
Place(3) = " Million, "
Place(4) = " Billion, "
Place(5) = " Trillion, "

Finally, prior to returning the result, check and remove the last character if it is a comma

Also, if there is a tens digit AND a ones digit, add a dash between them unless less than 20, i.e. add if Right(TensText, 1) <> "" ... and append an extra dash -... before appending the ones digit.

   ...
   Else ' If value between 20-99&hellip;
          Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
              Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
              Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
              Case 4: Result = "Forty "
              Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
              Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
              Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
              Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
              Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
              Case Else
          End Select
          ' Add a dash if >19 and has ones digit
          If Right(TensText, 1) <> "" and Result<>"" then
              Result = Result + "-"
          End If
          Result = Result & GetDigit _
              (Right(TensText, 1))  ' Retrieve ones place.
      End If

